# How to restore Android ListView position?

Tags: android, android-listview

I used this code to save list View position.
How i can restore it?

```
View c = listview.getChildAt(0);
int scrolly = -c.getTop() + listview.getFirstVisiblePosition() * c.getHeight();
```

Comment: it is better if you update the list and call notifydatasetchanged rather then resetting adapter, by doing that you won't require to reset your list position.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you all are looking:

onResume(){

```
   refresh_your_data();
    if(listview.getadapter()==null)
    // create the adapter
    }
    else
    {
    //create method in adapter to refresh list of data
    refill_data(listdata);
    adapter.notifydatasetchanged();
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can restore the saved position to the `ListView` by this method

```
listview.scrollListBy(scrolly);
```

If you want to scroll the list to top then you can use this

```
listview.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
```

Or

```
 listview.setSelection(0);
```

you can also use this method to scroll listview to top

```
listView.setSelectionAfterHeaderView();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Create Hashmap of listview item: 
HashMap<Integer, View> hashMap = new HashMap<Integer, View>();

//put listview items in hashmap
hashMap.put(position, view);

//get view item at particular position

hashMap.get(position);
```

Comment: what about `adapter.getView(position);`  :) Listview's adapter can give us all of the views.

Comment: In adapter getView method hashMap put and get code will come

Comment: when we have already all of the views with adapter and adpater can return the view at any desired position then what is the need of hasmap to put all of the views? It will consume too much memory

Comment: Because you want to save and retrieve listView item position, Using hashmap u can get your desired position view outside the getView method also. To manage memory after using hashMap clear it with hashmap.clear()